# Need to access a variable from all Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On the site I'm working on, there are users with different permissions on the site.

Given the schedule ID and employee ID that we're currently looking at, we can get their role-specific permissions.

Right now, our BaseModel has a property that properly accesses the DB and grabs this info.
For all views that pass a model to the view, everything runs fine.

The problem lies in Controller Methods where no model is passed. In a few views, all they're supplied is a few ViewBag entries, and work fine.

However, I /need/ the CurrentPermissions property in those pages nonetheless, for the layout. Whether or not the permissions have one boolean value set true/false, something may/may not be displayed/populated.

So, my option seem to be:

- Somehow throw my CurrentPermissions into a ViewBag entry for all views, and access them through that instead of the base model.

  - I'm not sure how to do this. I've seen people using OnActionExecuting, but that fails since my connection to TransactionManager is not yet set up at that point.
- Somehow throw just the BaseModel into those views that don't currently pass a model. I'm refraining from this as much as possible. I'm not sure how I would go about doing such, but it seems like that would over-complicate the situation.

How can I go about pushing this CurrentPermissions object (generated from a call to my TransactionManager) to every view (specifically, the Layouts!)

Comment: Please don't access DB from a model class... you cannot even call that class a model if it accesses the DB. Models can be filled by the controller, by MVC filters, but not by theirselves.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is what we use in out projects... and we use this approach to systematically remove the use of ViewBag changing it to ViewModels.

Other approach we have used (for UserPreferences in my case) is adding an ActionFilter that ends including the preference in the ViewBag.  You decorate the actions needing it with `[IncludePreferences]` in my case (that is the name of my filter attribute.

**EDIT ActionFilter:**

```
public class IncludePreferencesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
              var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;

              // IController is not necessarily a Controller
              if (controller != null)
              {
                     //I have my preferences in the BaseController
                     //and cached but here you can query the DB
                     controller.ViewBag.MyPreferences = controller.TenantPreferences;
              }
       }
}
```

In you action you decorate it using `[IncludePreferences]`

Comment: An ActionFilter might make the most sense in our case, but I have limitations as to what I can change. Adding a whole new ActionFilter for this seems a bit like overkill, so I can't justify it very well!

Comment: You can create an ActionFilter... and just use it in the actions you need it. If you like I can post the code I use in the action filter.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt; I might not use it, but it could be a good reference for the future so I can dive into ActionFilters at home some more!

Comment: When does the ActionFilter execute?

I previously tried to throw something similar into an OnActionExecuting override in the controller, but the timing was bad because the TransactionManager had not yet been set up. I suspect I would run into this again here, but I'll try to test.

Comment: I think in your case it is OK to do this in the OnActionExecuted, instead of in OnActionExecuting. I use OnActionExecuted to inject some values in the BaseViewmodel (to clean actions from repetitive code) and it is executed just before start rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I'm doing the following at the top of my Layout:

```
@{ OurModel.SupervisorRestriction CurrentSupervisorRestrictions = ViewBag.CurrentSupervisorRestrictions ?? Model.CurrentSupervisorRestrictions; }
```

This way, if we're passing in an object then it works just fine. Otherwise, I'll directly pass in a ViewBag.CurrentSupervisorRestrictions from the controller. There are only a few cases, so it's not that bad.

Better suggestions would be great, though.